# How do I escape an entire string without backslashes?

Tags: ios, swift, api, strongloop

I have this string here:

```
let toEscape = "http://localhost:3000/api/Tests/update?where={ \"name\": \(updateText) }"
```

This string would normally be fine, except that the API software (Strongloop) I am connecting to doesn't seem to like the backslashes at  \"name\". How do I escape the entire string so that I don't have to put backslashes before the quotes? In C# you can use an @ symbol at the beginning of a string, and supposedly you can do the same in Objective-C, but I haven't been able to do that in Swift, at least not so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create an NSURL with NSURL(scheme:host:path:) and call the absoluteString() method

```
let escapedString = NSURL(scheme: "http", host: "localhost:3000", path: "/api/Tests/update?where={ \"name\": \(updateText) }")?.absoluteString
```

**Edit:**

or still easier

```
let escapedString = toEscape.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: This definitely answers the question as far as how to escape a whole url string when sending the request. Now this is becoming a Strongloop question as it still doesn't like the request for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Yes, see answer above for URL encoding.

**Long answer**: Maybe the slashes aren't the problem. Using `\"` to escape double quotes has been standard for years in high-level languages, and is identified as proper syntax in the Swift docs (link above).

What I did notice is that your query parameter, if it's supposed to be JSON, is malformed. You would need quotes around the interpolated value for it to be valid JSON:

```
let toEscape = "...?where={ \"name\": \"\(updateText)\" }"
```

I have zero experience in Swift, nor have any experience in Strongloop, but I would try quoting `updateText` first and see if the problem changes.

Comment: Great point. That would probably fix it as well. I discovered that Strongloop offered an alternative way to write the URL instead, using [where][name]=\(updateText) instead of JSON.